# Unexpected result when moving bytes between buffers

Tags: c++, memory, vector

I am working on a function in c++ where the intent is to move `num_bytes` from one vector to another.

This is the relevent portion of my function

```
// Grab a pointer to the vector currently in use
std::vector<unsigned char> *bytes = &currentBuffer();

// Calculate un-parsed data in current vector                             
size_t num_bytes = static_cast<size_t>(currentBuffer().size() - pos_);

// Added in to test that it is working
std::cout << "Byte before: " << (*bytes)[pos_] << std::endl;

// Move num_bytes from pos_ in currentVector to [0] in otherBuffer
if (num_bytes) {                                              
   memmove(&(otherBuffer()[0]), &((*bytes)[pos_]), num_bytes);
}                                                             

// I now want to use otherBuffer as currentBuffer
bytes = &otherBuffer();                                            

// Reset size of new buffer
bytes->resize(num_bytes);                                     

// Reset position of new buffer
pos_ = 0;

// Added in to test that it is working                                   
std::cout << "Byte after: " << (*bytes)[pos_] << std::endl;
```

When I run this using real data I am getting two different results from the two cout statments, where ideally the byte value at `currentVector[pos_]` and `otherVector[0]` should be the same after the memmove.

Any clue what could be going wrong? I think the error is within `memmove` however I cannot figure out what it could be.

Thanks!

Comment: Your code could be massively simplified. For example, try copy a range using the tools C++ provides: `vector<unsigned char> result(source.begin() + start_index, source.begin() + start_index + count);`

Comment: @JimV - that seems to work: `otherBuffer() = std::vector<unsigned char>(bytes->begin() + pos_, bytes->begin() + pos_ + num_bytes); ` I Have a question though: does this new vector occupy the same memory location as otherBuffer() (which returns a reference to a vector). If not, is there any way this could be accomplished?

Comment: Why on earth would you want that? It's not clear what you're trying to do, or why you're trying to do it in such a convoluted fashion.

Comment: I am trying to minimize the amount of memory allocations I have to do. These vectors are realistically going to be massive, and ideally I should be able to do something like `vector.reserve()` upon creation of my object containing the vectors to grab a lot of space at once and then re-use the memory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to resize the buffer *before* you copy data to it, otherwise you risk writing beyond the internally allocated buffer of your other vector.

You'd be better off, however, using a classic C++ approach:

```cpp
otherBuffer().assign(currentBuffer().begin() + pos, currentBuffer().end());
```

All you need - no resize, no memmove (memcpy would probably have been more efficient in this case anyway...).

Comment: The vector has been resized - I do a `vector.reserve(large_size_here)` at the beginning of my program to allocate a lot of space once. Ideally I should not have to do another allocation, just reuse the memory that was initially reserved.

Comment: @wKavey `reserve` is *not* the same as `resize`. You've allocated the memory, but the `vector` hasn't initialized those locations yet. When it does, anything you might have put there will be wiped out.

Comment: I dont care about data being wiped - the idea for this is that the memory is reusable and I dont care about 'older' data that might be in there. Forgive me if im not making much sense, I may just not be grasping some fundamental idea here

Comment: Have a look at [resize()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/) - there is an additional default parameter! This one will be used to fill in data, if size is increased, overwriting in this case the data you filled in already. The assign function, on the other hand, won't reallocate anything either, if the internal buffer is large enough, which you achieved by the `reserve` already, as you said.

Comment: Yeah I think the assign function does exactly what I need it to - and there is logic in place to make sure that the size of what I am moving will never exceed what I originally reserved, so I dont think it will cause any allocations to occur

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `resize()` before the `memmove()`, not after.

Try this:

```
// Move num_bytes from pos_ in currentVector to [0] in otherBuffer
if (num_bytes) {                                              
   otherBuffer().resize(num_bytes);                                     
   memmove(&(otherBuffer()[0]), &((*bytes)[pos_]), num_bytes);
}
```

Comment: Of course, what you *should* do is delete all of this code and replace it with `otherBuffer().assign(...)`.